# Speed up operation on word and phrase count

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am using the scikit library to get a count of common two and three word phrases. The code works fine, but the sum operation on sparse_matrix takes over thirty minutes. Are there any ways to speed up that operation. I'd also be interested in other ways of doing this same task.

```
word_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(2,3), analyzer='word')
sparse_matrix = word_vectorizer.fit_transform(dat0['Description_Clean'].values.astype('U'))  
frequencies = sum(sparse_matrix).toarray()[0]
```

The Description_Clean column contains about 20,000 different values/strings

Comment: How big is the text you're parsing? 30 minutes is a *long* time. Do you just need the frequency of two and three consecutive words?

Comment: You probably want to use `sparse_matrix.sum()` instead of `sum(spares_matrix)`

Comment: @EricDuminil No, I dont need the frequency. Just want a data frame or list with those phrases